# Cannot boot Ubuntu 12.04 (no boot option)

Tags: 12.04, dual-boot, windows-8

This might be a common issue, but I cannot find any other words to describe my problem. After I uninstalled openSUSE and **deleted the boot option towards this OS** in order to have no trouble booting on Windows 8, I cannot boot ANY linux distro anymore after they're being installed. The reason why I post this on ASK UBUNTU is that Ubuntu is my favorite distribution and I an currently using it in a live device. I do not like Windows 8 that much (I got my ASUS laptop XC551CA less than two months ago).

I know what to do in order to get to the Ubuntu desktop on a live device. My problem is that I cannot find ANY boot option in the BIOS UEFI. I do not know how to add a boot option in the BIOS. I have tried Linux mint and openSUSE once more and both do not work.

I really need to get with Ubnutu as soon as possible. I need to keep video editing on kdenlive, I started several months ago and I can't do on a virtual machine on Windows (no! It doesn't work either and it is a painful experience!)

Anyone who experienced my problem and solved it, or anyone familliar with this issue is more than welcome to answer and/or comment!

As usual, I appreciate your time and wisdom. This is very urgent and I am pretty much un the rush.

Thank you!

Laptop identification:

ASUS X551CA X series

750 GB hard disk

Windows 8 alongside Ubuntu 12.04 LTS

Have tried several distros (and a windows program EasyBSD: unsuccessful!)

Experienced with installing and uninstalling linux distributions

Completely not experience with creating the boot options

Not really familliar with the BIOS

Boot repair ? Didn't work (both the CD and the program on the live USB that I downloaded once I booted onto Ubuntu)

Thank you again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've had a similar issue before where after installing Ubuntu 12.04 alongside Windows 7, it would never allow me to boot into Ubuntu. To solve the issue I utilized Boot Repair from a Ubuntu Live USB. There's an explanation of the tool located [here:](http://www.howtogeek.com/114884/how-to-repair-grub2-when-ubuntu-wont-boot/)

Comment: Thank you for this method. I used to have other GRUB issues before and therefore used this method as a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your answer. It may sound it little weird but I did not need to use Boot repair. As I said in my question above, I used Boot repair but nothing worked.

In fact, I downloaded an Ubuntu 12.04.3 64-bit image .iso instead of a 32-bit image .iso and installed Ubuntu successfully.

I rebooted and Grub was installed. I booted Ubuntu and everything worked fine!

So remember:

Although a 64-bit system can boot on a 32-bit image, use a 64-bit instead in order to use effeciently a system, espacially if it is a UEFI machine.

Thank you!